# How many subsets in sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let S = {1, 2, . . . , n} be a sample space. How many subsets of the sample
space have exactly two outcomes?

Im having difficulty understanding how i can answer this question. I know that there are $$2^n$$ subsets. But i do i know how many have exactly two outcomes?

Comment: How many ways can you choose $2$ elements from $n$ elements without regard to order?

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ counts precisely how many subsets of size $k$ from a set with $n$ elements exist.  Here, you have a set with $n$ elements and wish to count how many subsets of size $2$ exist... so, the answer to your question is $\binom{n}{2}$.  This is fundamental.  You should become very familiar with binomial coefficients.

Comment: OK that makes sense i get it now @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Presumably, you have seen combinations (i.e. $\binom n k$ or $_n C_k$). How might those be useful here?

**Alternate hint:** In case you're not familiar / comfortable with combinations: Suppose the size of my sample space is 10. If I want to choose an unordered list of 2 elements of this, then I have 10 options to choose for the first one, and 9 options for the second, for a total of 90 lists. But this double-counts every list, because a list like $\{a, b\}$ also appears as $\{b, a\}$; hence, I should cut the count in half. Now, how would this change for a general $n$?